# I am trying to work with 5 Dimensional arrays with a lot of steps. I get an error: ' 'std::bad_alloc' '

Tags: memory, coredump, bad-alloc

I am working for a problem which requires 5-dimensional arrays (dynamically allocated )with a number of steps of at least 1000. The code works fine for 50 steps. While, it gives an error of 'terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)
' when the number of steps is increased. Any suggestions ?

Comment: It seems you are running out of memory, as indicated by [`std::bad_alloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. yes. I did get that. But, what could be the way out?

Answer (score 0):

I was about to write another comment but it got too long...

You asked for a way out to std::bad_alloc, I can think in two options:

- Buy more RAM ;-)
- Stop allocating so much memory

Given that but you didn't provide any code and it is not clear what you mean with "steps", I will assume "steps" is the size of each one-dimensional array.

Now, consider a one-dimensional (standard) array. A char array of size 50 would require 50 contiguous bytes in memory.

For a 2-dimensional array, the required memory would be 50^50: 2500 bytes.

For a 3-dimensional array, the required memory would be 50^3: 125 KB.

Going up to a five-dimensional array, you would need 50^5 (312500000) bytes, roughly 300 MB (not necessarily contiguous because you usually allocate each sub-array using a nested `for loop`).

If the length of the array is **1000 instead of 50**, the required memory would be of 1000^5 (a 1 with 15 zeros at the right) bytes, almost a Petabyte!

And that's why you are running out of memory.